# Instance failing to boot from disk on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, libcloud

I'm trying to boot an instance on GCE through libcloud.

When I boot through the libcloud function, `ex_create_multiple_nodes` (with 1 machine specified), the instance and the disk are created successfully, and the disk is attached. I verify this through the developer console. No exceptions are thrown by the function call.

Unfortunately, the instance never boots successfully:

`...
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
...`

Full log: https://gist.github.com/danwinkler/dcf1351675eb8c744220
(This repeats again and again)

I've tested booting with the same parameters (snapshot, zone, size, etc.) through the developers console and it works fine.

A colleague pointed out that the error looks similar to those caused by virt-manager, but I don't see anything related to that in the docs or the console [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1638708).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error normally happens when you're trying to boot from an empty disk. You can attach the disk to another VM instance and check the disk contents to ensure that is has a valid and bootable partition.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the error was using a UEFI image. Google does not detect it automatically and you have to specify that you want to use UEFI at create time. Not sure if you can do it over the GUI, but Golang API code that does it can be found [here](https://github.com/edgelesssys/constellation/blob/ada66a64a12e12e2eadd5d8a775bfa3e377ae00a/internal/osimage/gcp/gcpupload.go#L155). If you want to create it from the CLI directly you can take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom) documentation.